# JQuery Validation - How to add rules?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I was trying to validate a textbox input via jquery, but I don't know how to apply certain rules for this kind of situation.

**Here is the deal:** I want the textbox to accept only alphanumeric inputs (A-Z and 0-9) and using ' . ' as separators for certain cases. If the textbox has a value of 16 (in this case, then the user must've typed something like this: 67EA981XXVT110TP), then I want to validate to check if there's only letters and numbers in the input, but if the value is 19 (something like: 67EA.981X.XVT1.10TP) then it has to be checked to confirm that the separators are in the right position (every 4 character input) and if there is only alphanumeric values in the field.

**This is what I was trying to do** (I'm using Razer Engine View)

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#txtCode').blur(function () {
                        if ($('#txtCode').val().length > 19) {
                            alert('Invalid field input!')
                        }
                        else if ($('#txtCode').val().length >= 1 && $('#txtCode').val().length < 16) {
                            alert('Invalid field input!')
                        }

                        if ($('#txtCodVerificador').val().length == 16) {
                            //check if there is only numbers and letters in the field
                        }

                        if ($('#txtCodVerificador').val().length == 19) {
                            //check if there is only numbers and letters in the field and if the separators are in the right place (every 4 character input)
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the regex matching and replacing in the keyup handler?

Comment: I was using to not allow special characters, I forgot to take that one out, sorry D:

Comment: I'm working on an answer for you, will have it shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$(function () {
  $('#txtCode').blur(function () {
    if ($('#txtCode').val().match(/^[A-Z0-9]{16}$/)) {
      console.log("Matches the 16");
    }else if ($('#txtCode').val().match(/^([A-Z0-9]{4}\.){3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$/)) {
      console.log("Matches the 19");
    }else{
      console.log("Does not match!");
    }
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pf8v0nc/15)

If you have any questions about the regex, ask away!

Comment: Awesome! Could you mark this question as solved by accepting either my or Stephen's answer?

Answer (score 2):

You have mentioned *I'm using Razer Engine View* so I assume this is [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc). Your current implementation means that you need to repeat all you validation again on the server when you submit. To handle this all out of the box, add a `RegularExpressionAttribute` to your property

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z0-9]{16}|([A-Z0-9]{4}\.){3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessage = "...")]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Code)
```

If your view includes `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`, then you get both client and server side validation (your `$('#txtCode').blur(..` script is not required)

Credit to ArcaneCraeda's answer for the regex.